# Apache Camel Check Directory Read Permission (AWS Environment)

Tags: apache-camel

I have an API for validating FTP directory as follows:

```
public boolean validateDirectory(FtpLocation ftpLocation) throws CustomException{
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try {
        client.connect(ftpLocation.getSystem(), Integer.parseInt(ftpLocation.getPort()));
        client.login(ftpLocation.getUser(), ftpLocation.getPassword());
        client.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpLocation.getDirPath());
        int returnCode = client.getReplyCode();
        if (returnCode == 550) {
            LOG.error("Directory ["+ ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "] does not exist");
            return false;
        }           
        File dir = new File(ftpLocation.getDirPath());
        if(dir!=null){
            if (!dir.canRead()) {
                LOG.error("Directory ["+ ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "] does not have read permission");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Failed to validate Source Directory Path [" + ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "]", e);
        throw new CustomException("Failed to validate Source Directory Path [" + ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "]", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.warn("Error occured while disconnecting FTPClient", e);
        }
    }   
}
```

My FTP root is **/** (*absolute path /home/soumya*)

I want to route files from **/source** (*absolute path /home/soumya/source*)

The following behaviors I found during the testing of my API:

1. if *source* with permission *rwxrwxr-x* then throws validation message (actually expecting a successful file routing).
2. if *source* with permission *-wx-wx--x* then validated successfully.
3. if *source* is not present then validated successfully.
4. if *source* is not a directory (source is a file) then validated successfully.

**Log is as follows for the above four scenarios:**

```
07:41:59.799 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR c.n.d.m.b.f.Validator - Directory [/source] does not have read permission

07:42:48.801 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR c.n.d.m.b.f.Validator - Directory [/source] does not have read permission

07:43:27.093 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR c.n.d.m.b.f.Validator - Directory [/source] does not exist

07:44:00.215 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR c.n.d.m.b.f.Validator - Directory [/source] does not exist
```

**Question:**

1. Is there any alternate way to solve the problem of 1, to route the files of *source* successfully ?
2. How to validate the directory to check the read permission ?

**NOTE:** Camel version is *2.12.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, here is it as follows:

```
public void validateDirectory(FtpLocation ftpLocation) throws CustomException {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try {
        client.connect(ftpLocation.getSystem(), Integer.parseInt(ftpLocation.getPort()));
        client.login(ftpLocation.getUser(), ftpLocation.getPassword());
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpLocation.getDirPath());
        int returnCode = client.getReplyCode();
        LOG.debug("FTP return code: "+ returnCode);
        if (returnCode == 550) {
            LOG.error("Directory ["+ ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "] does not exist");
            throw new CustomException("Directory ["+ ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "] does not exist");
        }
        String targetDir = client.printWorkingDirectory();
        client.cdup();
        targetDir = StringUtils.substring(targetDir, StringUtils.lastIndexOf(targetDir, File.separator) + 1);
        FTPFile ftpFiles[] = client.listFiles();
        for(FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles){
            if(StringUtils.equals(ftpFile.getName(), targetDir) && !ftpFile.hasPermission(FTPFile.USER_ACCESS, FTPFile.READ_PERMISSION)){
                LOG.error("No read permission for directory [" + ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "]");
                throw new CustomException("No read permission for directory [" + ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "]");
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Failed to validate Source Directory Path [" + ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "]", e);
        throw new CustomException("Failed to validate Source Directory Path [" + ftpLocation.getDirPath() + "]", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.warn("Error occured while disconnecting FTPClient", e);
        }
    }   
}
```

However if you have a better solution then please post it.